# Pycharm+Protocols - how to silence spurious 'Getter should return or yield something'

Tags: python, pycharm, protocols, static-analysis

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    @property
    def my_property(self) -> str:
        ...

class MyClass(MyProtocol):
    @property
    def my_property(self) -> str:
        # the actual implementation is here
```

pycharm complains the protocol doesnt return values. because its a protocol....

same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417586/how-to-define-a-property-as-part-of-a-protocol) but its been years no solution

also [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40180/Getter-should-return-or-yield-something-warning-shown-for-Protocol-properties) but 4 years with no solution

i'd like pycharm to fix their product, but in the meantime does anyone know a '# noqa' code i can use?

Answer (score 0):

The bug report you linked to suggests decorating with `@abstractmethod` as a work around.

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    @property
    def ...
```

Comment: yeah i saw that. dont like it, gets me confusing protocols and abcs. its not an abstract class, its a protocol... i just want to have pycharm ignore it